# With monitor not functioning, how do I edit Bios to recognize new Graphics Card?

Tags: display, bios, editing

I am hoping someone can tell me how to get my new graphics card working with no monitor. 
The mobo internal graphics card has apparently failed. 
I have installed a new graphics card. (GEFORCE GT 710)
I understand I need to edit the Bios for my pc to recognize the new card.
Any workarounds or instructions for the blind?
My Model No is HP p7-1439
Product # H3L17AA#ABA
Ser # MXX2450DM2
with Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried just plugging in the monitor to the new card? You shouldn't need to mess with the BIOS in this instance ...

Comment: "I need to edit the Bios for my pc to recognize the new card"; No; You don't

Answer (score 1):

You do **not** need to mess with BIOS after installing a graphics card.

After you get into Windows you need to install nVidia's drivers to get control of all the features but you will get an image to your display without messing with BIOS. Simple plug-n-play.

Comment: That's right. There is no BIOS settings for display devices to tweak in modern computers. Old computers had a "Palette Snooping" settings which I never needed to tweak.